# Firefox 3.5.5 won't install greasemonkey

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

i've been struggling with this for a while now: i can't install greasemonkey on my firefox portable 3.5.5 :( it must be something with the latest update to 3.5.5.
(i'm having win7 x64 ultimate)

upgrading greasemonkey didn't work so i completely de-installed it and then tried (no success):

- installing greasemonkey via addons-dialog
- installing .xpi manually
- installing with "restart firefox" button
- installing by quitting + restarting firefox

it simply just won't install / show up under addons.
of course i de-activated all other plugins and started firefox as administrator.

any ideas?

thx

Answer (score 2):

This has been covered in the [GreaseMonkey-users](http://groups.google.com/group/greasemonkey-users?lnk=srg) mailing list several times. There is an open bug being used to try and understand the problem (which a few people have, but most don't).